# Order of variables called by JVM

Tags: java

In what order variables (Static Variable,Local Variable,Instance Variable) will be called by Java Virtual Machine? If any class is having local,static & instance variable, then which variable will be called first & last by java virtual machine?

Comment: What do you mean with "called"? I think you mean initialized, but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static variable - Once when class gets loaded by class loader
local variable - Everytime when you call the method
instance variable - Everytime you create new object.